# Adding logging and instrumentation to an existing app

Tags: c#, .net, instrumentation

We have C++/CLI based application suite which has minimal logging (a handful of Debug::WriteLines) and no instrumentation.  We encounter issues on our client installations occasionally and I plan to significantly beef up both.  We need to be able to query (through a VPN) logs and instrumentation of these installations.

The plan for logging is to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging as a logging service/facade in front of System.Diagnostics and other outputs.

Instrumentation is a little more mysterious, and many seem oriented towards live profiling which is not our use case.  Ours is more SNMP-style behavior or even historic/logged querying.  As such, we plan to build our own .NET service/facade for instrumentation,  then mate that to a Prometheus.io queryable system as well as a CoAP endpoint (which shall serve different and unmentioned use cases)

This feels like we are reinventing a wheel - but so far I haven't found a better option.  How would you go about this if you were me?

Comment: Your question seems more applicable to the Software Engineering website of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't realized the distinction existed.  Perhaps a moderator can help me move the question there?

Comment: If you hover over the upper right icon in the SO header, you'll see help text of "A list of all 171 Stack Exchange sites". If you click on that icon, you'll get a the list of the other Stack Exchange sites, including the one for Software Engineering.